# my card component won't show on screen (ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a small project with ReactJs using props but my card component isn't displaying on my screen at all, I've looked for misspelling's/bugs and can't find any. Does anyone see the problem? (Using react version 18.2.0)

```js
import React from "react"
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import Card from "./components/Card"
import data from "./data"






export default function App() {
    const cards = data.map(item => {
      return (
        <Card 
        key= {item.id}
        item = {item}
        />
      )
    })

  return (
    <div>
      
      <Navbar />
      <section className="cards-list">
        {cards}
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: add values inside data file in question. is it a JSON file ?

Comment: @sojin no its a data.js file

Comment: Then what is the data it is returning ?. add both data and card component. or create a sandbox example.

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: try to put the output of console.log(data) in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **App** function to this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <section className="cards-list">
        {data.length !== 0 &&
          data.map((item) => {
            return <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
          })}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Code Improvement: You can use the ternary operator to check if the element is not null or undefined like this
data?.map((item) =>